# R: regression analysis between two numeric variables stratified by groups

Tags: r

Based on a user suggestion, I have posted this on CrossValidated:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468693/r-regression-analysis-between-two-numeric-variables-stratified-by-groups

I have the following data frame of 48 samples with the following columns: `sample` (sample identifier), `gene` (log2 gene expression of a randomly selected gene), `label` (exercised vs non-exercised mice), `strain` (strain of the mice), `weight` (weight of mice), `running.time` (how much time spent on treadmill) and `VO2max` (maximum O2 consumption).

```
> head(test)

  sample     label  strain weight   VO2max running.time     gene
1    A81 exercised ANT1 ME   28.8 6192.907     21.00000 18.26548
2    A13 exercised ANT1 ME   26.8 6598.627     22.25000 17.55368
3    A43 exercised ANT1 ME   26.4 6368.918     20.33333 17.45001
4    A76 exercised ANT1 ME   23.0 6947.636     18.41667 17.87199
5    A17 exercised ANT1 ME   25.8 6526.043     21.58333 17.64396
6    A30 exercised ANT1 ME   29.2 6562.106     20.58333 17.81958

> dput(test)

structure(list(sample = c("A81", "A13", "A43", "A76", "A17", 
"A30", "A58", "A75", "A82", "A88", "A4", "A18", "I50", "I94", 
"I75", "I59", "I63", "I84", "I13", "I95", "I18", "I100", "I62", 
"I85", "B69", "B80", "B11", "B9", "B98", "B4", "B70", "B19", 
"B85", "B3", "B10", "B47", "E56", "E76", "E12", "E78", "E1", 
"E50", "E42", "E64", "E98", "E100", "E7", "E53"), label = c("exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised"), strain = c("ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", 
"ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", 
"ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", 
"IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", 
"IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", 
"B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", 
"B6 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", 
"EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", 
"EC77 ME"), weight = c(28.8, 26.8, 26.4, 23, 25.8, 29.2, 27.6, 
25, 28.6, 29.4, 29, 29.2, 31.6, 29.9, 34, 32.5, 31.7, 31, 28.8, 
29.8, 27.9, 32.8, 32.1, 29, 32.2, 28.4, 30, 26.3, 27.8, 30.8, 
32.1, 28, 30, 35.3, 29.9, 29.6, 30, 31, 24, 25.8, 27.4, 30, 31, 
30.4, 28, 27.7, 26.25, 29.1), VO2max = c(6192.907, 6598.627, 
6368.918, 6947.636, 6526.043, 6562.106, 6626.237, 6464.229, 6692.121, 
6990.765, 6586.469, 6773.607, 7755.965, 8504.163, 8081.548, 7500.55, 
7693.678, 7909.825, 7588.132, 6710.412, 6846.685, 7498.796, 7196.46, 
7856.87, 7605.042, 8616.026, 7942.862, 8306.043, 7949.328, 8376.683, 
8480.413, 7422.928, 8006.701, 7987.724, 8091.422, 7622.233, 7396.47, 
7538.512, 7144.345, 7032.685, 6621.896, 7800.92, 6900.873, 7078.454, 
6846.685, 6165.303, 7327.488, 6787.016), running.time = c(21, 
22.25, 20.3333333333333, 18.4166666666667, 21.5833333333333, 
20.5833333333333, 18.75, 17.5833333333333, 20.9166666666667, 
20.9166666666667, 19.3333333333333, 19.6666666666667, 36.75, 
35.5, 33.5, 33.9166666666667, 31.3333333333333, 36, 33.0833333333333, 
33.1666666666667, 32.4166666666667, 34.1666666666667, 32.1666666666667, 
32.1666666666667, 37.3333333333333, 36.1666666666667, 33.6666666666667, 
36.4166666666667, 35.4166666666667, 35.5, 36.5833333333333, 33.8333333333333, 
34.4166666666667, 33.5833333333333, 35.6666666666667, 34.75, 
36.1666666666667, 31.1666666666667, 37.5, 31.6666666666667, 33.1666666666667, 
32.0833333333333, 33.5833333333333, 32.1666666666667, 32.4166666666667, 
31.25, 33.5833333333333, 31.5), gene = c(18.265481735128, 17.553682163378, 
17.450005832624, 17.8719936539426, 17.6439644306893, 17.8195797128757, 
17.7327533149751, 17.8626472422709, 18.4375411245124, 17.7206616316039, 
17.8324727651774, 17.6831637379254, 16.3797370363944, 16.2274547911749, 
16.1081681682918, 15.7581300013604, 16.3283156117628, 16.6112399890101, 
16.2097766576023, 16.353875382536, 16.1630593358039, 16.1941586675123, 
16.270535309697, 16.4154082664562, 16.0543656477653, 16.2056037427263, 
16.0414009536146, 15.8233199504989, 15.9644539321719, 16.0035065577481, 
15.1967778769911, 15.5873577174736, 15.4748920755074, 15.8414050703223, 
16.036749175609, 15.6950267375145, 16.2487211678851, 16.4280535060295, 
16.1600327464311, 15.9933079171589, 16.4159279247705, 15.8740001632907, 
16.2547699681823, 15.9199201254046, 15.7748035384056, 16.0895632695324, 
15.9950306563657, 16.1150404336735)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

I want to see if the gene expression `gene` (numeric) is correlated to the 
 continuous variable `VO2max` (numeric) across the two groups of exercised vs non_exercised (`label`) and four strains of mice (`strain`).

This is the model that I am thinking but not sure if I am correct:

```
# fit model
> fit <- lm(gene ~ VO2max + label + strain, data = test)

# output
> tidy(fit)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  term                 estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)        18.2        0.686       26.5   7.67e-28
2 VO2max             -0.0000434  0.000101    -0.430 6.69e- 1
3 labelnon_exercised -0.110      0.0767      -1.44  1.57e- 1
4 strainB6 ME        -1.93       0.176      -11.0   6.16e-14
5 strainEC77 ME      -1.70       0.111      -15.3   8.73e-19
6 strainIAI ME       -1.53       0.142      -10.8   1.21e-13
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach or how to interpret the results. Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: The code you are using looks OK to me. You might biologically want to include a VO2max : label interaction with `fit2 <- lm(gene ~ VO2max * label + strain, data = test)`. Whether this is the best model or the interpretation of the results is probably better asked on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks Ian, I am not sure what specifically interaction terms are. Should I be checking if VO2max is correlated to label (exercised or non-exercised) and then use the interaction term?

Comment: I'm just relying on physiology to make the recommendation. If you're exercising, your body needs more oxygen, and thus the [maximal oxygen consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max) will likely be higher. Therefore, it is likely that the effect of VO2max on gene expression will be different depending on label. I'm sure some hardcore statisticians will disagree with me, but alas, I am just a biologist.

Comment: @IanCampbell Can you tell me, just based on the output that I have shown, what are the different p-values telling? And which one should I be considering?

Comment: I would be concerned about an error in the data. The VO2max of the `ANT1 ME` strain is lower in the exercised state than non? Seems fishy. [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxgZr.png)

Comment: @IanCampbell You are right, that indeed seems weird. I will reach out to the person who gave me this file. Thanks for catching that.